# sending CFTypeRef (aka const void*) to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

A warning is raised in the following code. ARC is used.

```
if ( aAnim ) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:CFBridgingRetain([NSNumber numberWithInt:aOff])];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(postSpin:finished:toCCWCellOffset:)];
}
```

Comment: At which line? What's the definition of `aOff`?

Comment: @LoïsDiQual on line [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:CFBridgingRetain([NSNumber numberWithInt:aOff])] & aOff is an int.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CFBridgingRetain` returns a `CFTypeRef` which is declared as `const void *`.

The `context` parameter of `[UIView beginAnimations:context:]` is a `void *` (without
the `const`), hence the warning.

You can fix that warning by using `__bridge_retained` instead:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:(__bridge_retained void *)[NSNumber numberWithInt:aOff]];
```

Note that you have to balance that `retain` by releasing the context when it is no longer
used. This can for example be done in the "stop selector" by transferring the ownership
back to an Objective-C object:

```
id obj = (__bridge_transfer id)context;
```

Comment: can i use [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:(__bridge void *)[NSNumber numberWithInt:aOff]];

Comment: @Zubair: No, because the number object (which would be in the autorelease pool in this case) could be released before the animation is finished.