# What does this error even mean?

Tags: xcode, warnings

I got this error, and as I program xcode only at my house, I have no resources to quickly ask even the most simple 10 second questions. So this is one that came up today, I am using the AudioSessionAddPropertyListener function, and I get this warning:

passing 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *) to parameter of type 'void*' discards Qualifiers

from this line of code.

```
// Registers the audio route change listener callback function
// An instance of the audio player/manager is passed to the listener
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (  kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange, 
                                 audioRouteChangeListenerCallback,  CFBridgingRetain(self) );
```

then definition of the AudioSessionAddPropertyListener is

```
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(    AudioSessionPropertyID              inID,
                                AudioSessionPropertyListener        inProc,
                                void                                *inClientData)
```

and I see the *inClientData variable appears to be of type void (Or maybe not)

So what exactly might be the problem here, Mostly I would like to know what to look for when trouble shooting. I don't know what I don't know.

thanks

Steve

I'm not at 50 yet so I can't comment:

I looked at the definition of CFBridgingRetain
 it takes ID, and returns CFTypeRef

```
NS_INLINE CF_RETURNS_RETAINED CFTypeRef CFBridgingRetain(id X) {
    return (__bridge_retained CFTypeRef)X;
}
```

Now the definition of CFTypeRef is void
    /* Base "type" of all "CF objects", and polymorphic functions on them */
    typedef const void * CFTypeRef;

so in order to drop the warning I did this, cast the output of the function as (void *)

```
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (  kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange, 
                                 audioRouteChangeListenerCallback,  (void *) CFBridgingRetain(self) );
```

Does anyone see an issue with this?

Comment: check this topic 
[sending CFTypeRef (aka const void*) to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038376/sending-cftyperef-aka-const-void-to-parameter-of-type-void-discards-quali

Comment: I think you omitted `*` when you quoted the above message.  It's important.